# How to get the name of the month instead of the month number from db

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I am picking some data from the db to make some analytics in my website. I am rendering out the data graphically with the help of chart js.

This is how I am doing it in views,

**views.py**

```
    monthly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().filter(date_of_record__year = currentYear.year).values(
    'date_of_record__month'
    ).annotate(
        total_in_month=Count('ip') 
        ).order_by('date_of_record__month')
```

Here, I am picking up the data of all the visitors of every month of the current year. Now if I print the **monthly_visitor** I get the below result

```
<QuerySet [{'date_of_record__month': 9, 'total_in_month': 1}, {'date_of_record__month': 10, 'total_in_month': 2}, {'date_of_record__month': 11, 'total_in_month': 3}, 
{'date_of_record__month': 12, 'total_in_month': 5}]>
```

Which is correct but what I want is

```
<QuerySet [{'date_of_record__month': sept, 'total_in_month': 1}, {'date_of_record__month': oct, 'total_in_month': 2}, {'date_of_record__month': nov, 'total_in_month': 3}, 
{'date_of_record__month': dec, 'total_in_month': 5}]>
```

So that I can display names of the month in the graph rather the numbers. I came across some methods to use tags in the html. But I am importing this data into a different javascript file with the help of ajax.

Please suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code works, for PostgreSQL you can do it this way:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField

monthly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().filter(
    date_of_record__year=currentYear.year
).values(
    'date_of_record__month'
).annotate(
    total_in_month=Count('ip'),
    formatted_date=Func(
        F('created_at'),
        Value('Month'),
        function='to_char',
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).order_by('date_of_record__month')
```

I'm using the [formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html), so this code is RDBMS-dependent.

You will also have a `date_of_record__month` in `QuerySet`, you don't have to pass it to the response.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am getting this output now

[{'date_of_record__month': 9, 'total_in_month': 1, 'formatted_date': 'September'}, {'date_of_record__month': 10, 'total_in_month': 2, 'formatted_date': 'October  '}, {'date_of_record__month': 11, 'total_in_month': 3, 'formatted_date': 'November '}, {'date_of_record__month': 12, 'total_in_month': 5, 'formatted_date': 'December '}]>

Comment: But what I am doing then is that I appending it to a list and then passing the list to ajax, the code is,

 for i in range(len(monthly_visitor)):

        visitorMonthNumber.append(monthly_visitor[i]['date_of_record__month'])
        visitorNumberMonthly.append(monthly_visitor[i]['total_in_month'])

Comment: How do I get the names in the graph as i cannot loop through the formatted date, therfore only the numbers are getting appended in the list

Comment: Could you please post the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code after changes? I'm not sure why exactly you couldn't access `formatted_date`.

Comment: I am editing the question just a minute

Comment: Now it is working sir, I was getting a weird exception error that I didi not understand, and now it has started working again. Anyways Thank you very much for your ans.